# Como replicar um valor dependendo do que está dentro da célula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou com um código que coloca sempre 264 caracteres vazios depois da última palavra digitada dentro da célula; em seguida coloca mais "00000000000000" depois dos 264 caracteres vazios e exporto para txt, como mostro abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é tenho que colocar no final da linha depois dos 264 caracteres sempre "99999999999999" que na célula estiver com o seguinte campo preenchido : 5497558138889999999999998

Segue meu código:

```
Sub Macro14()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim arq1 As Long
Dim name As String
Dim op As Variant
Dim linha As Long
Dim res As String

On Error GoTo fim:

linha = 1

While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TesteConcluido").Cells(linha, 1) <> ""

name = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TesteConcluido").Cells(linha, 1)

While Len(name) < 265

name = name + " "

Wend


If linha = 42 And 43 Then

name = name & "999999999990000"

Else

name = name & "000000000000000"

End If

arq1 = FreeFile

Open fileTeste For Append As arq1

Print #arq1, name

Close #arq1
linha = linha + 1
Wend

fim:
If Err.Number = "70" Then

Resume

End If

MsgBox "O arquivo foi exportado com sucesso! ", vbInformation, "Exportar arquivos"

res = MsgBox("Você gostaria voltar ao menu?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "QNIS - CAIXA")

If res = vbYes Then

Else

ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
Unload FormQNIS
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Você poderia marcar algumas respostas das perguntas que fez como [aceitas e respondidas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/75104). Assim mais pessoas estarão dispostas a ajudá-lo. Para mais informações sobre o SOpt, leia o [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/75104)

Comment: Tudo bem respondi as outras perguntas, obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue solução do problema:

```html
Option Explicit

Sub Macro14()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim arq1 As Long
Dim name As String
Dim op As Variant
Dim linha As Long
Dim res As String
Dim texto As String

texto = "54975581388899999999999"


On Error GoTo fim:
    
linha = 1

While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TesteConcluido").Cells(linha, 1) <> ""
     
name = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TesteConcluido").Cells(linha, 1).Value)
    
While Len(name) < 265
            
name = name + " "
            
Wend

If InStr(1, name, texto, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

name = name & "999999999990000"

Else

name = name & "000000000000000"

End If
       
arq1 = FreeFile

Open fileTeste For Append As arq1

Print #arq1, name

Close #arq1
linha = linha + 1
Wend

fim:
If Err.Number = "70" Then

Resume

End If

MsgBox "O arquivo foi exportado com sucesso! ", vbInformation, "Exportar arquivos"

res = MsgBox("Você gostaria voltar ao menu?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "QNIS - CAIXA")
    
If res = vbYes Then
  
Else

ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
Unload FormQNIS
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```